# How convert sql query to linq-to-sql

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql

I have Sql query:

```
SELECT News.NewsId, News.Subject, Cm.Cnt FROM dbo.News
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT Comments.OwnerId, COUNT(Comments.OwnerId) as Cnt 
 FROM Comments 
 WHERE Comments.CommentType = 'News' 
 Group By Comments.OwnerId) Cm
ON Cm.OwnerId = News.NewsId
```

But I want linq-to-sql query, how I can convert this to linq?

Comment: What do you have so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find it helpful to download [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/), which will make it extremely easy to write LINQ and test it. It will also help you learn the syntax. Awesome tool. And it's free.

Answer (score 1):

> how I can convert this to linq?

Practice! :)

```
from news in News
let count = news.Comments
  .Where(comment => comment.CommentType == "News")
  .Count()
select new {news.NewsId, news.Subject, Count = count};
```